# Python read from JSON file value and write to csv modify some values

Tags: python

I have a JSON file loaded and written to CSV in this way:

```py
# Opening JSON file and loading the data
# into the variable data
with open('personal.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

employee_data = data['results']
#inventory_data = data['inventory']

print (inventory_data)

#print(f'Total users: {res.json().get("total")}')

# now we will open a file for writing
data_file = open('data_file.csv', 'a')

# create the csv writer object
csv_writer = csv.writer(data_file)

# Counter variable used for writing
# headers to the CSV file

count = 0

for emp in employee_data:
    if count == 0:

      # Writing headers of CSV file
      header = emp.keys()
      csv_writer.writerow(header)
      count += 1

# Writing data of CSV file
    csv_writer.writerow(emp.values())

data_file.close()
```

Works perfect there is no problem at all. This is the example of some JSON file created by this:

```json
{
    "count": 1100,
    "next": "https://any.com/?limit=10&offset=10",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "list_no": "00011",
            "item_no": "MZVL2256HC",
            "upc_code": "",
            "manufacturer_no": "MZVL2256HCHQ-00",
            "manufacturer": "SAMSUNGOEM",
            "category": "SSD",
            "product_name": "Samsung PM9A1 - SSD - 256 GB - PCIe 4.0 x4 (NVMe)",
            "price": 56.65,
            "instant_rebate": "",
            "instant_rebate_item_no": "",
            "weight": 0.06,
            "unit": 300,
            "length": 14.75,
            "width": 12.0,
            "height": 3.75,
            "package": "BULK",
            "specorder": "Y",
            "is_domestic_only": "N",
            "inventory": {
                "": 50
            }
        },
        {
            "list_no": "00012",
            "item_no": "MZVL2512HC",
            "upc_code": "",
            "manufacturer_no": "MZVL2512HCJQ-00",
            "manufacturer": "SAMSUNGOEM",
            "category": "SSD",
            "product_name": "Samsung PM9A1 MZVL2512HCJQ - SSD - 512 GB - PCIe 4.0 x4 (NVMe)",
            "price": 70.04,
            "instant_rebate": "",
            "instant_rebate_item_no": "",
            "weight": 0.06,
            "unit": 300,
            "length": 23.0,
            "width": 17.0,
            "height": 10.0,
            "package": "BULK",
            "specorder": "Y",
            "is_domestic_only": "N",
            "inventory": {
                "": 55
            }
        },
        {
            "list_no": "00013",
            "item_no": "MZVL21T0HC",
            "upc_code": "",
            "manufacturer_no": "MZVL21T0HCLR-00A00",
            "manufacturer": "SAMSUNGOEM",
            "category": "SSD",
            "product_name": "Samsung PM9A1 MZVL21T0HCLR - SSD - 1 TB - PCIe 4.0 x4 (NVMe)",
            "price": 105.06,
            "instant_rebate": "",
            "instant_rebate_item_no": "",
            "weight": 0.06,
            "unit": 300,
            "length": 23.0,
            "width": 17.0,
            "height": 10.0,
            "package": "BULK",
            "specorder": "Y",
            "is_domestic_only": "N",
            "inventory": {
                "": 52,
                "M": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "list_no": "00014",
            "item_no": "MZVL22T0HB",
            "upc_code": "",
            "manufacturer_no": "MZVL22T0HBLB-00A00",
            "manufacturer": "SAMSUNGOEM",
            "category": "SSD",
            "product_name": "Samsung PM9A1 - SSD - 2 TB - PCIe 4.0 x4 (NVMe)",
            "price": 187.46,
            "instant_rebate": "",
            "instant_rebate_item_no": "",
            "weight": 0.06,
            "unit": 300,
            "length": 23.0,
            "width": 17.0,
            "height": 10.0,
            "package": "BULK",
            "specorder": "Y",
            "is_domestic_only": "N",
            "inventory": {
                "": 58
            }
        },
        {
            "list_no": "00102",
            "item_no": "MT48RD64A1",
            "upc_code": "649528921666",
            "manufacturer_no": "MTC40F2046S1RC48BA1R",
            "manufacturer": "MICRON",
            "category": "MEM",
            "product_name": "Micron - DDR5 - module - 64 GB - DIMM 288-pin - 4800 MHz / PC5-38400 - registered",
            "price": 297.67,
            "instant_rebate": "",
            "instant_rebate_item_no": "",
            "weight": 0.09,
            "unit": 100,
            "length": 14.75,
            "width": 12.0,
            "height": 3.75,
            "package": "BULK",
            "specorder": "Y",
            "is_domestic_only": "Y",
            "inventory": {
                "": 36,
                "L": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "list_no": "00104",
            "item_no": "MT48RD32A1",
            "upc_code": "649528921598",
            "manufacturer_no": "MTC20F2085S1RC48BA1R",
            "manufacturer": "MICRON",
            "category": "MEM",
            "product_name": "Micron - DDR5 - module - 32 GB - DIMM 288-pin - 4800 MHz / PC5-38400 - registered",
            "price": 164.8,
            "instant_rebate": "",
            "instant_rebate_item_no": "",
            "weight": 0.1,
            "unit": 100,
            "length": 14.75,
            "width": 12.0,
            "height": 3.75,
            "package": "BULK",
            "specorder": "N",
            "is_domestic_only": "N",
            "inventory": {
                "": 53
            }
        },
        {
            "list_no": "00105",
            "item_no": "MT48RS32A2",
            "upc_code": "649528921529",
            "manufacturer_no": "MTC20F1045S1RC48BA2R",
            "manufacturer": "MICRON",
            "category": "MEM",
            "product_name": "Micron - DDR5 - module - 32 GB - DIMM 288-pin - 4800 MHz / PC5-38400 - registered",
            "price": 164.8,
            "instant_rebate": "",
            "instant_rebate_item_no": "",
            "weight": 0.1,
            "unit": 100,
            "length": 14.75,
            "width": 12.0,
            "height": 3.75,
            "package": "BULK",
            "specorder": "N",
            "is_domestic_only": "Y",
            "inventory": {
                "": 38
            }
        },
        {
            "list_no": "00108",
            "item_no": "MT48RS16A1",
            "upc_code": "649528921376",
            "manufacturer_no": "MTC10F1084S1RC48BA1R",
            "manufacturer": "MICRON",
            "category": "MEM",
            "product_name": "Micron - DDR5 - module - 16 GB - DIMM 288-pin - 4800 MHz / PC5-38400",
            "price": 95.79,
            "instant_rebate": "",
            "instant_rebate_item_no": "",
            "weight": 0.09,
            "unit": 100,
            "length": 14.75,
            "width": 12.0,
            "height": 3.75,
            "package": "BULK",
            "specorder": "N",
            "is_domestic_only": "Y",
            "inventory": {
                "": 364,
                "L": 50
            }
        },
        {
            "list_no": "00116",
            "item_no": "MT48E32A1",
            "upc_code": "649528931481",
            "manufacturer_no": "MTC20C2085S1EC48BA1R",
            "manufacturer": "MICRON",
            "category": "MEM",
            "product_name": "Micron - DDR5 - module - 32 GB - DIMM 288-pin - 4800 MHz / PC5-38400 - unbuffered",
            "price": 164.8,
            "instant_rebate": "",
            "instant_rebate_item_no": "",
            "weight": 0.09,
            "unit": 100,
            "length": 14.75,
            "width": 12.0,
            "height": 3.65,
            "package": "BULK",
            "specorder": "N",
            "is_domestic_only": "Y",
            "inventory": {
                "": 32,
                "N": 0,
                "L": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "list_no": "00118",
            "item_no": "MT48E16A1",
            "upc_code": "649528931429",
            "manufacturer_no": "MTC10C1084S1EC48BA1R",
            "manufacturer": "MICRON",
            "category": "MEM",
            "product_name": "Micron - DDR5 - module - 16 GB - DIMM 288-pin - 4800 MHz / PC5-38400 - unbuffered",
            "price": 95.79,
            "instant_rebate": "",
            "instant_rebate_item_no": "",
            "weight": 0.09,
            "unit": 100,
            "length": 14.75,
            "width": 12.0,
            "height": 3.75,
            "package": "BULK",
            "specorder": "N",
            "is_domestic_only": "Y",
            "inventory": {
                "": 21
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The issue I have is with one column created in the csv called inventory I have some values as:

`"inventory": {"": 52, "N": 57, "L": 34, "M": 15}`

or

`"inventory": {"": 21}`

Can be clearly seen in the JSON text. What I want is that all instances in inventory to that instances I want to make a sum of all that values appear there and that sum that is the value to send to the column inventory. Why? Because actually it sends me to csv as that I copied literal and they don’ work for the purpose. In primer example the value in inventory would be 52+57+34+15=158 and second example 21 and like that with all values. How can I modify the code to do that?

Thank you

I tried to investigate how to call values. For example:

`employee_data = data['results']`

This variable reads the values in the JSON file as count, results, etc but after results I don’t know how to call the values as list_no, inventory, etc.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the sum of inventory with return all values from `inventory` dict from `data['results']`. Then you can call `list_no` data with iterate `data['results']` with single data `i` and make `i['list_no']` to get the data. These codes should be works:

```
import json
# Opening JSON file and loading the data
# into the variable data
with open('personal.json') as json_file:
  data = json.load(json_file)
employee_data = data['results']

for i in employee_data:
  # calculate sum of Inventory data
  sumOfInventory = sum(list(i['inventory'].values()))

  # print a few data
  print('List_No :', i['list_no'])
  print('Inventory :', i['inventory'])
  print('Sum of Inventory :', sumOfInventory)
  print('----------------------')

  # insert that sum into the json data
  i['sumOfInventory'] = sumOfInventory

#print new json data
print('new json data :')
print(employee_data)
print('')

#inventory_data = data['inventory']

# print (inventory_data)

#print(f'Total users: {res.json().get("total")}')

# now we will open a file for writing
data_file = open('data_file.csv', 'a')

# create the csv writer object
csv_writer = csv.writer(data_file)

# Counter variable used for writing
# headers to the CSV file

count = 0

for emp in employee_data:
  if count == 0:
    # Writing headers of CSV file
    header = emp.keys()
    csv_writer.writerow(header)
    count += 1

  # Writing data of CSV file
  csv_writer.writerow(emp.values())

data_file.close()
```

The console output must be like this :

```
List_No : 00011
Inventory : {'': 50}
Sum of Inventory : 50
----------------------
List_No : 00012
Inventory : {'': 55}
Sum of Inventory : 55
----------------------
List_No : 00013
Inventory : {'': 52, 'M': 0}
Sum of Inventory : 52
----------------------
List_No : 00014
Inventory : {'': 58}
Sum of Inventory : 58
----------------------
List_No : 00102
Inventory : {'': 36, 'L': 0}
Sum of Inventory : 36
----------------------
List_No : 00104
Inventory : {'': 53}
Sum of Inventory : 53
----------------------
List_No : 00105
Inventory : {'': 38}
Sum of Inventory : 38
----------------------
List_No : 00108
Inventory : {'': 364, 'L': 50}
Sum of Inventory : 414
----------------------
List_No : 00116
Inventory : {'': 32, 'N': 0, 'L': 0}
Sum of Inventory : 32
----------------------
List_No : 00118
Inventory : {'': 21}
Sum of Inventory : 21
----------------------
new json data :
[{'list_no': '00011', 'item_no': 'MZVL2256HC', 'upc_code': '', 'manufacturer_no': 'MZVL2256HCHQ-00', 'manufacturer': 'SAMSUNGOEM', 'category': 'SSD', 'product_name': 'Samsung PM9A1 - SSD - 256 GB - PCIe 4.0 x4 (NVMe)', 'price': 56.65, 'instant_rebate': '', 'instant_rebate_item_no': '', 'weight': 0.06, 'unit': 300, 'length': 14.75, 'width': 12.0, 'height': 3.75, 'package': 'BULK', 'specorder': 'Y', 'is_domestic_only': 'N', 'inventory': {'': 50}, 'sumOfInventory': 50}, {'list_no': '00012', 'item_no': 'MZVL2512HC', 'upc_code': '', 'manufacturer_no': 'MZVL2512HCJQ-00', 'manufacturer': 'SAMSUNGOEM', 'category': 'SSD', 'product_name': 'Samsung PM9A1 MZVL2512HCJQ - SSD - 512 GB - PCIe 4.0 x4 (NVMe)', 'price': 70.04, 'instant_rebate': '', 'instant_rebate_item_no': '', 'weight': 0.06, 'unit': 300, 'length': 23.0, 'width': 17.0, 'height': 10.0, 'package': 'BULK', 'specorder': 'Y', 'is_domestic_only': 'N', 'inventory': {'': 55}, 'sumOfInventory': 55}, {'list_no': '00013', 'item_no': 'MZVL21T0HC', 'upc_code': '', 'manufacturer_no': 'MZVL21T0HCLR-00A00', 'manufacturer': 'SAMSUNGOEM', 'category': 'SSD', 'product_name': 'Samsung PM9A1 MZVL21T0HCLR - SSD - 1 TB - PCIe 4.0 x4 (NVMe)', 'price': 105.06, 'instant_rebate': '', 'instant_rebate_item_no': '', 'weight': 0.06, 'unit': 300, 'length': 23.0, 'width': 17.0, 'height': 10.0, 'package': 'BULK', 'specorder': 'Y', 'is_domestic_only': 'N', 'inventory': {'': 52, 'M': 0}, 'sumOfInventory': 52}, {'list_no': '00014', 'item_no': 'MZVL22T0HB', 'upc_code': '', 'manufacturer_no': 'MZVL22T0HBLB-00A00', 'manufacturer': 'SAMSUNGOEM', 'category': 'SSD', 'product_name': 'Samsung PM9A1 - SSD - 2 TB - PCIe 4.0 x4 (NVMe)', 'price': 187.46, 'instant_rebate': '', 'instant_rebate_item_no': '', 'weight': 0.06, 'unit': 300, 'length': 23.0, 'width': 17.0, 'height': 10.0, 'package': 'BULK', 'specorder': 'Y', 'is_domestic_only': 'N', 'inventory': {'': 58}, 'sumOfInventory': 58}, {'list_no': '00102', 'item_no': 'MT48RD64A1', 'upc_code': '649528921666', 'manufacturer_no': 'MTC40F2046S1RC48BA1R', 'manufacturer': 'MICRON', 'category': 'MEM', 'product_name': 'Micron - DDR5 - module - 64 GB - DIMM 288-pin - 4800 MHz / PC5-38400 - registered', 'price': 297.67, 'instant_rebate': '', 'instant_rebate_item_no': '', 'weight': 0.09, 'unit': 100, 'length': 14.75, 'width': 12.0, 'height': 3.75, 'package': 'BULK', 'specorder': 'Y', 'is_domestic_only': 'Y', 'inventory': {'': 36, 'L': 0}, 'sumOfInventory': 36}, {'list_no': '00104', 'item_no': 'MT48RD32A1', 'upc_code': '649528921598', 'manufacturer_no': 'MTC20F2085S1RC48BA1R', 'manufacturer': 'MICRON', 'category': 'MEM', 'product_name': 'Micron - DDR5 - module - 32 GB - DIMM 288-pin - 4800 MHz / PC5-38400 - registered', 'price': 164.8, 'instant_rebate': '', 'instant_rebate_item_no': '', 'weight': 0.1, 'unit': 100, 'length': 14.75, 'width': 12.0, 'height': 3.75, 'package': 'BULK', 'specorder': 'N', 'is_domestic_only': 'N', 'inventory': {'': 53}, 'sumOfInventory': 53}, {'list_no': '00105', 'item_no': 'MT48RS32A2', 'upc_code': '649528921529', 'manufacturer_no': 'MTC20F1045S1RC48BA2R', 'manufacturer': 'MICRON', 'category': 'MEM', 'product_name': 'Micron - DDR5 - module - 32 GB - DIMM 288-pin - 4800 MHz / PC5-38400 - registered', 'price': 164.8, 'instant_rebate': '', 'instant_rebate_item_no': '', 'weight': 0.1, 'unit': 100, 'length': 14.75, 'width': 12.0, 'height': 3.75, 'package': 'BULK', 'specorder': 'N', 'is_domestic_only': 'Y', 'inventory': {'': 38}, 'sumOfInventory': 38}, {'list_no': '00108', 'item_no': 'MT48RS16A1', 'upc_code': '649528921376', 'manufacturer_no': 'MTC10F1084S1RC48BA1R', 'manufacturer': 'MICRON', 'category': 'MEM', 'product_name': 'Micron - DDR5 - module - 16 GB - DIMM 288-pin - 4800 MHz / PC5-38400', 'price': 95.79, 'instant_rebate': '', 'instant_rebate_item_no': '', 'weight': 0.09, 'unit': 100, 'length': 14.75, 'width': 12.0, 'height': 3.75, 'package': 'BULK', 'specorder': 'N', 'is_domestic_only': 'Y', 'inventory': {'': 364, 'L': 50}, 'sumOfInventory': 414}, {'list_no': '00116', 'item_no': 'MT48E32A1', 'upc_code': '649528931481', 'manufacturer_no': 'MTC20C2085S1EC48BA1R', 'manufacturer': 'MICRON', 'category': 'MEM', 'product_name': 'Micron - DDR5 - module - 32 GB - DIMM 288-pin - 4800 MHz / PC5-38400 - unbuffered', 'price': 164.8, 'instant_rebate': '', 'instant_rebate_item_no': '', 'weight': 0.09, 'unit': 100, 'length': 14.75, 'width': 12.0, 'height': 3.65, 'package': 'BULK', 'specorder': 'N', 'is_domestic_only': 'Y', 'inventory': {'': 32, 'N': 0, 'L': 0}, 'sumOfInventory': 32}, {'list_no': '00118', 'item_no': 'MT48E16A1', 'upc_code': '649528931429', 'manufacturer_no': 'MTC10C1084S1EC48BA1R', 'manufacturer': 'MICRON', 'category': 'MEM', 'product_name': 'Micron - DDR5 - module - 16 GB - DIMM 288-pin - 4800 MHz / PC5-38400 - unbuffered', 'price': 95.79, 'instant_rebate': '', 'instant_rebate_item_no': '', 'weight': 0.09, 'unit': 100, 'length': 14.75, 'width': 12.0, 'height': 3.75, 'package': 'BULK', 'specorder': 'N', 'is_domestic_only': 'Y', 'inventory': {'': 21}, 'sumOfInventory': 21}]
```

Comment: Wonderful it worked very good real good. i see you created the column sumOFinventory to avoid overwrite the original one that’s good. Thank you for the help